# Problema con enrutado de aplicacion en React Native con EXPO

Tags: react-native, router, expo

esta es mi primer pregunta! quisiera saber si me pueden pasar la forma correcta de enrutar una app con expo-router... He intentado de varias maneras y no logro hacer que funcione.
Mi ultimo intento fue este =>

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { Route, Switch } from "expo-router";

import Welcome from "./src/Views/Welcome";
import Login from "./src/Views/Login";
import Landing from "./src/Views/Landing";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Welcome} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="/landing" component={Landing} />
      </Switch>
    </View>
  );
}
```